# Dicas de como fazer duas excerpts dentro de cada artigo do wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Preciso de dicas de como criar excerpts (resumos) no Wordpress, eu tenho um pouco de conhecimento na plataforma, mas ainda muito limitado e não sei por onde começar.

Tem dois resumos dentro de cada artigo do blog, uma forma padrão. Onde será limitado os caracteres a serem exibidos. Já busquei informação em diversos locais e não encontrei.

Da mesma forma da imagem abaixo. Com o texto resumido em umas 6 linhas e "VER MAIS"

Eu não tenho código ainda, porque eu realmente não sei por onde começar. Preciso de dicas, informações, links, qualquer coisa que me dê um "norte".

[image: Exemplo do link "ver mais"]

Comment: Não é o que você marcou. Estava revisando o conteúdo. Mas fico muito agradecido pela ajuda. Não tem bootstrap , gostaria que no painel administrativo , tivesse dois campos , onde escrevo os artigos. Quando for publicado , os caracteres do conteúdo são limitados. É padrão o número de linhas para mostrar para os usuários. No meu , vai ser 6 linhas. Da mesma forma do layout da Udemy.

Comment: Retirei o voto. Eu entendi. Ele vai mostrar as 6 primeiras linhas, mas se tiver 3 linhas apenas? E o conteúdo interno, pode ter um com 8 linhas e outro com 80 linhas?

Comment: Sim , não importa o tanto de linhas que terá no conteúdo interno. Caso tenha menos de 6 linhas , o conteúdo é mostrado sem a função "Ver mais", mas caso tenha acima de 6 linhas , terá o "Ver mais" , pode ter 7 linhas , que o conteúdo será limitado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tem um modelo simples que pode te ajudar. Caso seu texto tenha menos de 6 linhas basta vc remover o "Leia mais"

A técnica é usar uma `Label` com um `for` para o `checkbox` que está escondido fora do `.box`. Quando esse `checkbox` for marcado clicando na `label` a `.box` aumenta e mostra o conteúdo todo. Como o `.box` tem altura `max-height` ele sempre vai ajustar com o seu conteúdo, a não ser que ele tenha mais que 1000px de altura, o que é algo bem improvável, mas se precisar tb basta mudar esse valor...

Veja funcionando para vc entender melhor. ***Deixei os comentários no código para te ajudar***

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.box {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin: 1rem;
/* altura inicial do box, mude aqui o suficiente para mostrar quanto quiser do conteúdo inicial */
 max-height: 200px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0 1rem 2rem;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: max-height 500ms;
}
input:checked + .box {
 max-height: 1000px;
 /* hake para fazer o box crescer, o tamanho máximo dele é 1000px ou menosse o conteúdo for menor */
}
.box > label {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 1rem;
 height: 3rem;
 line-height: 3rem;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fff 25%);
 color: red;
}
.box > label:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
#ler {
 display: none; 
 /* remove o checkbox da tela */
}
```

```html
<!-- quando o input for checado o box cresce -->
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="ler" hidden>
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
    <p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
    <p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
    <p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
    <p>5 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
    <p>6 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
    <p>7 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
    <p>8 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, aut!</p>
  </div>
  <!-- label para checar o checkbox quando for clicada -->
  <label for="ler">leia mais</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hugo , não sei como te agradecer. Muito obrigado. De coração.

Comment: @GMSan Que legal jovem! Fico feliz de ter ajudado. Se vc acha que seu problema foi resolvido considere marcar a resposta como Aceita **✓**. Assim ela não fica pendente no site como pergunta não resolvida.

Comment: @GMSan ficou faltando alguma coisa? Achei que tinha funcionado ai...